# Dynamic variable name in python

Tags: python, django

I'd like to call a query with a field name filter that I wont know before run time... Not sure how to construct the variable name ...Or maybe I am tired.

```
field_name = funct()
locations = Locations.objects.filter(field_name__lte=arg1)
```

where if funct() returns name would equal to

```
locations = Locations.objects.filter(name__lte=arg1)
```

Not sure how to do that ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a dictionary, set the parameters and pass this to the function by [unpacking the dictionary as keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```
field_name = funct()
params = {field_name + '__lte': arg1,       # field_name should still contain string
          'some_other_field_name': arg2}

locations = Locations.objects.filter(**params)

# is the same as (assuming field_name = 'some_name'):
# Locations.objects.filter(some_name__lte=arg1, some_other_field_name=arg2)
```

Comment: You need another `_` in `some_name_lte` in your last comment line.