# Can you modify variable before declaring it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, global

I have hundreds of variables (here is only few of them so you'll get idea how this code works) and I have no idea how to solve this problem. What I want to do is in second if statement to somehow modify variable before declaring it so I could copy class to it so I could bypass many needless if satements. Is it possible?

This code in second if statement of course is incorrect

```
globals()["p%sg%sr01_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)
```

but this is what I'd like to achieve before declaring variable to which I'll copy class

```
import copy
cp = "01"
awsg = "01"
temp1 = 0
temp2 = 0

first_hovered_variable = "01"
second_hovered_variable = "02"


class Char():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.n = name

p01g01r01_id = Char("A1")
p01g01r02_id = Char("B2")
p01g01r03_id = Char("C3")

reg01_id = Char("001")
reg02_id = Char("002")
reg03_id = Char("003")


def swap_variables():
    global cp
    global awsg

    global temp1
    global temp2

    global first_hovered_variable
    global second_hovered_variable

    global reg01_id
    global reg02_id
    global reg03_id

    global p01g01r01_id
    global p01g01r02_id
    global p01g01r03_id

    if first_hovered_variable == second_hovered_variable:
        first_hovered_variable = 0
        second_hovered_variable = 0

    elif first_hovered_variable != 0 and second_hovered_variable != 0:
        temp1 = copy.copy(globals()["p%sg%sr%s_id" % (cp, awsg, second_hovered_variable)])
        temp2 = copy.copy(globals()["p%sg%sr%s_id" % (cp, awsg, first_hovered_variable)])

        if first_hovered_variable == "01":
            reg01_id = copy.copy(temp1)
            globals()["p%sg%sr01_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)

        elif first_hovered_variable == "02":
            reg02_id = copy.copy(temp1)
            globals()["p%sg%sr02_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)

        elif first_hovered_variable == "03":
            reg03_id = copy.copy(temp1)
            globals()["p%sg%sr03_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)    

        if second_hovered_variable == "01":
            reg01_id = copy.copy(temp2)
            globals()["p%sg%sr01_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)    

        elif second_hovered_variable == "02":
            reg02_id = copy.copy(temp2)
            globals()["p%sg%sr02_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)

        elif second_hovered_variable == "03":
            reg03_id = copy.copy(temp2)
            globals()["p%sg%sr03_id" % (cp, awsg)]) = copy.copy(temp1)

    temp1 = 0
    temp2 = 0

swap_variables()
print p01g01r01_id.n
print p01g01r02_id.n
print p01g01r03_id.n

print reg01_id.n
print reg02_id.n
print reg03_id.n
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "variable declaration" or "variable initialization" in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable name in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564140/dynamic-variable-name-in-python)

Comment: Your code is, to be perfectly frank, horrible. You have huge amounts of repetition (immediate sanction from the Redundancy Department of Redundancy), loads of `global` variables, a pointless class, huge amounts of repetition, ... Once you do get this working, consider visiting [codereview.se] for some feedback.

Comment: Try to go *with* the language rather than *against* it.

Comment: You've got a typo on those lines - get rid of the extra close paren so that they look like `globals()["..." %(cp, awsg)] = copy.copy(temp1)`

Comment: Variables can't be modified, only what they point to.

Comment: Classes are pointless because it wouldn't do any good to code transparency if I would make them much more complicated. Sometimes guys it would be nice if you could just try to focus on question not how code looks like. I could tell you that hovered variable changes whole time etc etc but it's not important. What is important for me is question asked.

Comment: That's why I commented; I know it's not an answer to your question. *"it wouldn't do any good to code transparency if I would make them much more complicated"* - but it would improve it if you got rid of them altogether. My point is that you can get help for your broader problems, too; as this is a site for professional and enthusiastic programmers (per the [tour]), I tend to assume that OPs have *some* interest in improving their skills.

Comment: I want to copy class and I want to do this with globals() I think it's important that you know that I want to do this. Variables are also simple because it's not important if it's "1" or "Harvey Jones" but that it is there and it is used. I'm new and I want to learn but instead of that you just trash what you see without telling me how I can improve. This is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Gunnm *"I think it's important that you know that I want to do this"* - and I think it's important that you know that there are other, better ways of approaching the problem. *"without telling me how I can improve"* - I *am* telling you how you can improve; **get your code reviewed!** Note also that you need to include `@username` to notify other users that you're addressing them.

Comment: If your code needs hundreds of `if` statements to work, *you are doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set new globals directly in the `globals()` directory, without ever using any other assignments to those names.

However, you should consider creating a separate dictionary or list for your instances instead. That way you can address those instances as a group.

For your 3 dimensions, you could even produce a nested structure:

```
characters = [
    [
        [Char(letter + digit) for letter, digit in zip('ABC', '123')]
        for g in range(3)
    ] for p in range(3)
]
```

Do the same for your 3 `reg` variables; store those in a list too.

Now you can address `characters[0][1][2]` to get `Char('C3')` at that position. Store those indices in variables and you can use *those* to address different positions:

```
reg[first_hovered_variable] = characters[cp][awsg][first_hovered_variable]
```

and you removed a whole set of `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you for answer I try to use your code but I keep getting:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @Gunnm: my apologies, I forgot to include the `zip()` call.

Comment: Thank you for help. It works. I hope that more people here will help others like you do.